# Nuxt serverMiddleware deploying to Vercel Serverless Function not finding Axios

Tags: nuxt.js, serverless, vercel

I'm trying to utilize [Vercel's Serverless Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions) with [Nuxt's serverMiddleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/) as outlined in [vercel-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/vercel-builder).

The function is simple, just making a http request using axios:

~/api/index.js

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import axios from 'axios'

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/api/product', async function (_, res) {
    const url = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/list?types=ITEM'
    const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer abc`
    }
    const result = await axios.get(url, { headers })

    res.status(200).send(result.data)
})

export default app
```

It works fine locally, however when deployed to Vercel, I get the following error in the functions logs:

```
ERROR   Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs'
ERROR   Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
```

Axios is defined in the package.json:

```
...
"engines": {
  "node": "16.x"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
  "axios": "1.2.1",
  "body-parser": "1.20.1",
  "core-js": "^3.19.3",
  "express": "4.18.2",
  "got": "12.5.3",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
  "vue": "^2.6.14",
  "vue-gtag": "1.16.1",
  "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
  "vue2-touch-events": "3.2.2",
  "webpack": "^4.46.0"
},
...
```

nuxt.config.js

```
  ..
  serverMiddleware: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [] : ['~/api/index.js']
  ..
```

vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/product",
      "dest": "/api/index.js"
    }
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
       "src": "/api/index.js",
       "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
       "src": "nuxt.config.js",
       "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder",
       "config": {
          "serverFiles": ["api/**"]
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried switching to use require() and a number of edits to nuxt.config.js and vercel.json to no avail.